# Why is std::aligned_storage defined through a nested struct "::type" rather than using the templated class directly?

Tags: c++, templates, types, language-lawyer

Both the standard in http://eel.is/c++draft/depr.meta.types#11

and cppreference suggest a typical implementation of `std::aligned_storage` would look somewhat like this (the standard differs minimally):

```
template<std::size_t Len, std::size_t Align = /* default alignment not implemented */>
struct aligned_storage
{
    struct type
    {
        alignas(Align) unsigned char data[Len];
    };
};
```

i.e. by exposing a nested type that includes the actual array. This bears the danger of users mistakenly using `std::aligned_storage` directly instead of `std::aligned_storage::type`, which, I believe, was one of the reasons for its being deprecated. What might be the reason for such a definition? Why couldn't it have been implemented as

```
template<size_t Len, size_t Alignment>
struct aligned_storage {
    alignas(Alignment) unsigned char __data[Len];
};
```

?

Do the rules of the standard regarding "providing storage" etc. require such a definition?

Comment: You have already linked to the requirements - `type` is a typedef that is properly aligned. That's all. The rest is just an example. Note that C++11 was 13 years in the making, and some features proposed early might have been outdated already before the release...

Comment: `aligned_storage` was already added to C++, first in a TR, in 2003 ([N1519](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2003/n1519.htm)) and it existed already in boost before that. `alignas` wasn't available yet, so that implementation wouldn't have work anyway. Instead it had to be implemented as a union with a suitably aligned type for the inner type. Although I guess that doesn't answer why the outer wrapper type is necessary. Maybe just because all transforming type traits added at the time were specified like that (take input as template arguments, provide result as `::type`)?

Comment: "_Do the rules of the standard regarding "providing storage" etc. require such a definition?_": The concept of "providing storage" was only added with C++17, much later.

Comment: `std::aligned_storage` is deprecated in C++23. Do not invest any further on that. Instead use `std::aligned_alloc` function and wrap the call in a class to get required type-safty.